# AWS Signing and Javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rhino

I need to send HTTP request to AWS with signed request via Javascript. Sadly I cannot use the AWS SDK JS as its either for Node.js or browser, but I need to run it from Rhino JS environment.
seems I am doing something very wrong as I get whatever I do same result - AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials.
 :(

The code I am using is same as the one Amazons is using as example (but in Python). I am using only one external lib so I can use HMCA &SHA. 
Any help is much appreciated (and needed as I am struggling for days by now...), so yeah - help!

Thanks is advance!
Cheers,

Joro

```
gs.include('jshashes');

var method = 'GET';
var service = 'ec2';
var host = 'ec2.amazonaws.com';
var region = 'us-east-1';
var endpoint = 'https://ec2.amazonaws.com';
var access_key = 'ACCESSKEY';
var secret_key = 'SECRET/KEY';
var request_parameters = 'AWSAccessKeyId' + access_key + 'Action=RunInstances&&ImageId=ami-b770fbd8';

function getSignatureKey(key, date, region, service){
  var newKey = "AWS4" + key;
  var kDate = new Hashes.SHA256().b64_hmac(newKey, date); 
  var kRegion = new Hashes.SHA256().b64_hmac(kDate, region); 
  var kService = new Hashes.SHA256().b64_hmac(kRegion, service); 
  var kSigning = new Hashes.SHA256().b64_hmac(kService, "aws4_request"); 

  return kSigning;
}

var gdt = new GlideDateTime();
var datestamp = gdt.getDate().getByFormat('yyyyMMdd') + 'T' + 
gdt.getTime().getByFormat('HHmmss') + 'Z';
var amzdate = gdt.getDate().getByFormat('yyyyMMdd')+"";

var canonical_uri = '/'; 

var canonical_querystring = request_parameters;

var canonical_headers = 'host:' + host + '\n' + 'x-amz-date:' + amzdate + '\n'
var signed_headers = 'host;x-amz-date';

var payload_hash = new Hashes.SHA256().hex(""); 

var canonical_request = method + '\n' + canonical_uri + '\n' + canonical_querystring + '\n' + canonical_headers + '\n' + signed_headers + '\n' + payload_hash;

var algorithm = 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256';
var credential_scope = datestamp + '/' + region + '/' + service + '/' + 'aws4_request';
var string_to_sign = algorithm + '\n' +  amzdate + '\n' +  credential_scope + '\n' +  new Hashes.SHA256().hex(canonical_request);

var signing_key = getSignatureKey(secret_key, datestamp, region, service);
//Python
//var signature = hmac.new(signing_key, (string_to_sign).encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
var signature = new Hashes.SHA256().hex_hmac(signing_key, string_to_sign);

var authorization_header = algorithm + ' ' + 'Credential=' + access_key + '/' + credential_scope + ', ' +  'SignedHeaders=' + signed_headers + ', ' + 'Signature=' + signature

var headers = {'x-amz-date':amzdate, 'Authorization':authorization_header}

var request_url = endpoint + '?' + canonical_querystring

var httpRequest = new GlideHTTPRequest(request_url);
httpRequest.setRequestHeader(headers);
var res = httpRequest.get();
gs.print(res.statusCode);
gs.print(res.allHeaders);
gs.print(res.body);
```

Comment: Just eyeballing the code quickly it looks like your URL parameters are malformed: key1=Val&key2=Val... Seems cleaner if you were to use json to build queries rather than string concatenation everywhere.

Comment: Guess JSON is better, but this is the example Amazon gave, so I just followed and made it in JS. Still same error - with fixed params (forgot = and had && insead of & )

Comment: Perhaps you'd like to update the code to show what you are actually using?

Comment: I am not sure if I am using the right algoritm to encode the strings and tehe key. Amazon says : {code} def sign(key, msg):
    return hmac.new(key, msg.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).digest()

def getSignatureKey(key, dateStamp, regionName, serviceName):
    kDate = sign(('AWS4' + key).encode('utf-8'), dateStamp)
    kRegion = sign(kDate, regionName)
    kService = sign(kRegion, serviceName)
    kSigning = sign(kService, 'aws4_request')
    return kSigning {code}

Comment: While I am using this : 

 new Hashes.SHA256().rstr_hmac(newKey, date); 
  var kRegion = new Hashes.SHA256().rstr_hmac(kDate, region); 
  var kService = new Hashes.SHA256().rstr_hmac(kRegion, service); 
  var kSigning = new Hashes.SHA256().rstr_hmac(kService, "aws4_request"); 
  
  return kSigning;
}`code`
The docs for this lib I am using says  : Calculate the HMAC-sha256 of a key and some data (raw strings).
Somay be I am missing something there?

Comment: 1. AWS includes JavaScript reference implementations in their documentation so you don't need to transcode from a Python sample. Even without looking at the specifics I can say your implementation does not exactly match the AWS reference. 2. Please update (edit) your original question to show *exactly* what relevant code you are using if you would like more specific feedback. You alluded to fixing some typos but there are many so it is hard to comment.

Comment: Hi,
it was the URL - badly formed , after I managed to fix it I got 200 from AWS. But I cant browse the instances for example - I get empty list. Any idea what rights/groups are required ? I manage to do DescribeRegions only (for which one I got Not Authorized before I add a group) but thats all I am able to do.
About the JS reference - yes they have but its only for the JS SDK they provide, so the signing is not shown as JS code.

Comment: I would suggest checking the behavior with a tool like [awscli](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/).

Answer (score 1):

Check the URL construction. For one, the `request_parameters` have some missing and misplaced delimiters.

```
var request_parameters = 'AWSAccessKeyId=' + access_key +
                         '&Action=RunInstances&ImageId=ami-b770fbd8';
```

In addition to inspecting and testing the resulting URL, you might also try to simply the syntax to make it easier to check and update.  Just as an example, the following

```
var credential_scope = datestamp + '/' + region + '/' + service + '/' + 'aws4_request';
var string_to_sign = algorithm + '\n' +  amzdate + '\n' + credential_scope + '\n' + new Hashes.SHA256().hex(canonical_request);
```

could be written as follows (which seems easier to check to me):

```
var credential_scope = [
    datestamp,
    region,
    service,
    'aws4_request'
].join('/');

var string_to_sign = [
    algorithm,
    amzdate,
    credential_scope,
    new Hashes.SHA256().hex(canonical_request)
].join('\n');
```